# Check whether a SAS date is valid before using MDY()?

Tags: sas

Is there a way to check whether three variables `(month, day, year)` can actually build a `valid SAS date format` before handing those variables over to `MDY()` (maybe except checking all possible cases)?

Right now I am dealing with a couple of thousand input variables and let SAS put them together - there are a lot of date variables which cannot work like `month=0, day=33, year=10 etc.` and I'd like to catch them. Otherwise I will get way too many `Notes` like

```
NOTE: Invalid argument to function MDY(13,12,2014)
```

which then eventually culminate in `Warnings` like

```
WARNING: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached.  Further errors of this type will not be printed.
```

I really would like too prevent getting those `Warnings` and I thought the best way would be to actually check the validity of the date - any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an INFORMAT instead, then you can use the ?? modifier to suppress errors.

```
month=0;
day=33;
year=10;
date = input(cats(put(year,z4.),put(month,z2.),put(day,z2.)),??yymmdd8.);
```

[SAS documentation: ? or ?? (Format Modifiers for Error Reporting)](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1g8q3l1j2z1hjn1gj1hln0ci5gn.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting - haven't heard of `modifiers` before! Just tested it, works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I added a (if edit gets approved) [link](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1g8q3l1j2z1hjn1gj1hln0ci5gn.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) explaining some details of `?,?? modifiers` - hope that's all right with you.